# Changing MYSQL server to match new rails application version KEY, CONSTRAINT, and COLUMN

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

**SETTING**

I have a rails application that references an external mysql server. I am about to push some changes to the rails application. I made some changes to my local/test version of the application's database using rails migrations, but my production/live version of the application's database is not on a server that has the rails application, so I don't think I can just run the rails migration on the mysql database.

**QUESTION**

How do I safely add the following column, key and constraint:

```
  `item_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `index_notifications_on_item_id` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_f395ae520f` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `items` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

and safely change the unique key:

```
UNIQUE KEY `item_id_and_user_id_stand_id_unique_index` (`item_id`,`user_id`,`stand_id`)
```

to

```
UNIQUE KEY `item_id_and_user_id_stand_id_notified_user_id_unique_index` (`item_id`,`user_id`,`stand_id`,`notified_user_id`),`)
```

**ATTEMPTS**
**CONCERNING THE CONSTRAINT AND  KEY**

I try running:

```
ALTER TABLE notifications ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_rails_f395ae520f(item_id) REFERENCES items(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

But, I run into 2 issues:

1: It names the key what I want the constraint to be named and makes up its own constraint name.

OUTPUT:

```
KEY `fk_rails_f395ae520f` (`item_id`),
CONSTRAINT `notifications_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `items` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

2. It requires me to temporarily set:  `set foreign_key_checks = 0;` or else I get the error:

   ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`DB_NAME`.`#sql-3c9_49`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-3c9_49_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `items` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

and I do not know if doing that is "safe" to do on a production/live server.

**CONCERNING THE COLUMN AND UNIQE KEY**

I believe I have the column and unique keys safely added with:

```
ALTER TABLE notifications add COLUMN item_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE notifications DROP INDEX index_notifications_on_user_id_and_notified_user_id, ADD UNIQUE KEY `item_id_and_user_id_stand_id_notified_user_id_unique_index` (stand_id, user_id, notified_user_id, item_id);
```

**CLARIFICATION**

The reason I bring up the column and unique key even though I may have it working is the same reason I gave a setting: I am new to this and may be taking a flawed approach to the whole scenario. I am hoping this context allows someone to call me out on it if that's the case.

**UPDATE 1**

```
ALTER TABLE notifications ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rails_f395ae520f FOREIGN KEY index_notifications_on_item_id(item_id) REFERENCES items(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

outputs:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_f395ae520f` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `items` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

Which is what I want, but I am still working on the KEY section.

**UPDATE 2**

```
ALTER TABLE notifications add COLUMN item_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE notifications DROP INDEX index_notifications_on_user_id_and_notified_user_id, ADD UNIQUE KEY `item_id_and_user_id_stand_id_notified_user_id_unique_index` (stand_id, user_id, notified_user_id, item_id);
CREATE INDEX index_notifications_on_item_id ON notifications (item_id);
ALTER TABLE notifications ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rails_f395ae520f FOREIGN KEY index_notifications_on_item_id(item_id) REFERENCES items(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I believe these four lines in sequence answers the question of how to manually handle what my rails migration does. But, I am going to leave this question here. The question that remains is: "is it a terrible idea to do what I just did? and if so, how to do proceed?"